# Why can't we prove that sum of internal torques always sum to zero from Newton's laws?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

We can argue that internal forces on a body add up to zero by saying that forces are created in pairs (third law) inside the system and hence the net sum must be zero. Similarly we by the third law of rotational dynamics, we should be able to argue the same for rotations.

However, it is written in the book of Kleppmer and Kolenkow: introduction to mechanics, that it is not possible to prove that internal torques sum to zero using newton's laws and we must accept it as an experimental fact. Why exactly does my previously stated argument fail?

Thanks to @Rosnaik I figured out my argument was indeed correct. However, I do wish to know what Kleppner was trying to say here.

---

Reference page-260, under dynamics and fixed axis rotation

Comment: http://www.basic-physics.com/m9-vanishing-of-total-internal-torque/#:~:text=According%20to%20excellent%20experimental%20evidence,equivalent%20of%20Newton's%20third%20law.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have two particles 1 and 2 interacting with each other. Force on 1 by 2 is $F_{12}$ and force on 2 by 1 is $F_{21}$. From Newton's third law it follows that $F_{12} = - F_{21}$. Now let's calculate the torque of this two particle system.
$$\tau_{internal} = \mathbf{r_1} \times \mathbf{F_{12}} + \mathbf{r_2} \times \mathbf{F_{21}}$$
$$ = (\mathbf{r_1} - \mathbf{r_2}) \times \mathbf{F_{12}}$$
When does this torque vanish? It vanishes when $\mathbf{r_1} - \mathbf{r_2}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{F_{12}}$. In other words, the net internal torque in a system is zero only when the internal forces are central, i.e., if they point along the line connecting the two particles.

Remember Newton's laws do not require this. Newton's third law only says the forces have to be equal and opposite. It does not say that they also have point along the connecting vector. That depends on the nature of forces. You have to do some extra experiments to find that out. If, experimentally you find that there are non central forces between particles, then internal torque cannot be zero.

Comment: Could you give suggestions for further reading/ where you got this from ?

Comment: And this answer contradicts with the other answer which is said.. hmm EDIT: that the force is along the line is assumed in mit video! 

Could you give an example where force of two interacting particle is not along the line joining two particles?

Comment: Magnetic forces is one such example. I'm too lazy to go into the details but I'm pretty sure Kleppner discusses this in considerable detail in the next chapter

Comment: Ok I just checked and Kleppner doesn't go into the details, he just mentions electromagnetic interaction as an example. Take a look at section 8.5 of Kleppner for a deeper discussion of what i said

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: "Newton's laws do not require this [...] You have to do experiments to find that out" – as currently written, I think this is misleading since it suggests that angular momentum conservation is more of an empirical question than linear momentum conservation. The reality is Newton just happened to write down one of the conservation laws and not the other. They're equally in need of experimental validation.

Comment: Yes I agree. I'm not that very good at expressing myself in English

Comment: Once you set out the framework of newton's law, what experimental verification do you need? I took newton's law as 'axioms' and everything else as theorems.

Comment: Newton's laws don't hold inside of matter where objects in motion tend to stop. They don't even hold on the surface of Earth, which is not an inertial system. Objects in motion "magically" accelerate towards the floor. So whether Newton's laws are correct or not depends on the local environment, and that is an experimental question.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of the internal torques was not zero, then the system could undergo spontaneous angular acceleration in violation of conservation of angular momentum (and energy).